# JupyterLab: Run all cells below

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-lab

In the Jupyter Notebook I could use the following command to automatically execute all cells below the current cell.

```
from IPython.display import Javascript
display(Javascript('IPython.notebook.execute_cells_below()'))
```

However, this doesn't seem to work with JupyterLab. How can I make this work for JupyterLab?
(I want to automatically execute all cells below after a button click occured. The original code for this was posted here: [IPython - Run all cells below from a widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32714783/ipython-run-all-cells-below-from-a-widget))

Answer (score 17):

It is built-in. Click the run menu at the top-left and select `"Run Selected Cell and All Below".`

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but I want to do it automatically on certain events (e.g. button clicked) like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32714783/ipython-run-all-cells-below-from-a-widget

Comment: Oh I see...I misunderstood the question. The issue is probably related to the fact that JavaScript execution was limited in JupyterLab(https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/3748). Maybe this extension can help you out https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/tree/master/packages/javascript-extension

Comment: Humm...It seems they re-enabled javascript execution in v0.33(https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/changelog.html). I am not sure what the issue is then.

Comment: Is this still an issue? I want to do exactly that, but it seems not possible

Comment: In the setup explained in my answer, the commando is called "Notebook: Execute Cell and below". I've installed this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter

Answer (score 1):

Installing [this Jupyter extension in VS-Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter), both the commando `"Notebook: Execute Cell and Below"` and the button in the top-left of each cell are built-in.

The commands can be opened with `"CTRL + SHIFT + P"`.

**Commando "Notebook: Execute Cell and Below"**
[image: jupyter_notebook_execute_cell_and_below_1]

**Button in the top-left of each cell:**
[image: jupyter_notebook_execute_cell_and_below_2]

Answer (score 1):

with ipylab you can run (some) JupyterLab backend commands in frontend, so installing ipylab in jupyter:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
app = JupyterFrontEnd()
def run_all(ev):
    app.commands.execute('notebook:run-all-below')

button = widgets.Button(description="Run all below")
button.on_click(run_all)
display(button)
```

And more, you can create your own Jupyterlab Scripts (Like a matplotlib instruction)

Answer (score 0):

This might be possible with ipylab. However, in JupyterLab 3.2.3 ipylab does not seem to work.

Also see
[How to cause Jupyter Lab to save notebook (programmatically)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66880698/how-to-cause-jupyter-lab-to-save-notebook-programmatically)