# "Run All Below" action in JupyterLab programatically

Tags: jupyter-lab

Is there a functionality in JupyterLab to programmatically run all the cells below a specific one?
I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61205846/run-cell-programatically-in-jupyterlab) on StackOverflow but couldn't find out how can I integrate it into my individual JupyterLab.

Comment: Do you use a specific programming language with JupyterLab (e.g. Python, Julia, R), or are you looking for language-agnostic solution to integrate with an extension (which is not really such agnostic as this would be JSON/JavaScript).

Comment: Well, I will leave https://github.com/jtpio/ipylab just in case but this question really needs more focus.

Comment: I am using Python in JupyterLab and I am would preferably look for a solution based on Python, as I am not that experienced with JS.

Answer (score 1):

In Jupyterlab using Python, you can create a Button (ipywidgets) to execute a script and with ipylab you can execute backend commands in frontend, like this:

```
from ipylab import JupyterFrontEnd
import ipywidgets as widgets
app = JupyterFrontEnd()
def run_all(ev):
    app.commands.execute('notebook:run-all-below')

button = widgets.Button(description="Run all below")
button.on_click(run_all)
display(button)
```

The "ipylab" is more powerful than this, that can run all backend JupyterLab commands or you can create your own commands (Like a matplotlib instruction)