# How to run the specific cells below (or above) in Jupyter Lab?

Tags: jupyter, ipython, jupyter-lab

I am using jupyterlab 3.6.7 and notebook 6.5.6 (jupyterlab_pygments 0.3.0, jupyterlab-widgets 3.0.9) with python. I would like to write a code to automatically run the next and subsequent cells after the current cell is run.

I can use this below code to run the next cell and the next 2 cells in Jupyter Notebook. It works fine with no problems on Jupyter-notebook  (6.5.6).

```
from IPython.display import Javascript
display(Javascript('IPython.notebook.execute_cell_range(IPython.notebook.get_selected_index(), IPython.notebook.get_selected_index()+2)'))
```

as shown below.
[image]

But if running on Jupyter Lab (3.6.7), an error occurs.
`Javascript Error: IPython is not defined`

Is it possible to run these codes on Jupyter Lab? If so, how do I do it?

Selected Jupyter core packages...

```
IPython          : 8.12.3
ipykernel        : 6.29.0
ipywidgets       : 8.1.1
jupyter_client   : 7.4.9
jupyter_core     : 5.7.1
jupyter_server   : 2.12.5
jupyterlab       : 3.6.7
nbclient         : 0.9.0
nbconvert        : 7.14.2
nbformat         : 5.9.2
notebook         : 6.5.6
qtconsole        : 5.5.1
traitlets        : 5.14.1
```

`Not using matplotlib`

Comment: That statement about the method you say works in Jupyter Notebook is inaccurate because you aren't using current Jupyter Notebook. Please add version numbers for that, too. It won't work in Jupyter Notebook 7+ because it is built on the same tech as JupyterLab. You may be able to use [ipylab](https://github.com/jtpio/ipylab#ipylab) to do this. I don't know of an example close to this but I'll try to look into it later. If you want to investigate on your own, I would search around the Jupyter Discourse Forum in addition to here for references to 'ipylab'.

Comment: [This post](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/interrupt-a-cell-mid-execution-run-another-cell-then-continue-first-cell/18186?u=fomightez) at least mention the command that is used to specify to run cells. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71944114/8508004) includes a snippet of code to 'Run All Below' and so that looks to get towards one of your goals. I say one because your title mentions above while your post text only mentions below. [Another answer there to 'JupyterLab: Run all cells below'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70382452/8508004) looks useful for your effort, too.

Comment: @Wayne Sorry for late reply. I use notebook version 6.5.6 (already added), not 7.

Comment: That makes sense then because according to [here](https://blog.jupyter.org/jupyter-notebook-6-5-0-release-candidate-4c229c6dab55) then you'd be using the older tech that is different than JupyterLab. But when you try the same approach with JupyterLab it isn't going to work and you need ipylab. Those running Jupyter Notebook 7+ now and in coming months and years won't see what you saw with 6.5.6 though and so thanks for distinguishing now.

Comment: @Wayne 

After receiving your advice I tried looking into ipylab, but it seems there are only commands to run all cells, run cell above/below only. There are no commands that can be executed on specific cells. Or I do miss something.

Comment: According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64676066/8508004) you can run the currently selected cells. I don't know what ways there are that you can build that selection programmatically though.