# How to cause Jupyter Lab to save notebook (programmatically)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have a notebook that runs overnight, and prints out a bunch of stuff, including images and such. I want to cause this output to be saved programatically (perhaps at certain intervals). I also want to save the code that was run. In a Jupyter notebook, you could do:

```
from IPython.display import display, Javascript
display(Javascript('IPython.notebook.save_checkpoint();'))
# causes the current .ipynb file to save itself (same as hitting CTRL+s)
```

(from [Save an IPython notebook programmatically from within itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32237275/save-an-ipython-notebook-programmatically-from-within-itself))

Although, I found that this javascript injection did not work in Jupyter lab(Jupyter not found). My question is how to do the equivalent of the above code in Jupyter lab. Upon inspecting the HTML of the jupyter lab, I could not find the Jupyter object.

Comment: Cross-referencing relevant discussion on GitHub: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/6161

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [ipylab](https://github.com/jtpio/ipylab) to access JupyterLab API from Python. To save the notebook just invoke the `docmanager:save` command:

```py
from ipylab import JupyterFrontEnd

app = JupyterFrontEnd()
app.commands.execute('docmanager:save')
```

You can get the full list of commands with `app.commands.list_commands()`.

Comment: I get an empty list in Jupyterlab 3.2.3 and ipylab 0.5.2

Comment: Did you restart JupyterLab after installing `ipylab`?

Comment: yes  ----------------

Comment: Hmm. I saw something like that once and never again. Would you mind reporting it on https://github.com/jtpio/ipylab/issues with any logs in the browser console and terminal?

Comment: https://github.com/jtpio/ipylab/issues/82   "Module ipylab, semver range ^0.5.2 is not registered as a widget module"

Comment: is there an option to save to a different path?

Comment: in jupyterlab 3.6.1, app.commands.list_commands() returns empty list.

Comment: Did you restart JupyterLab after installation?

Comment: @alancalvitti One thing that can cause the empty list of commands is if the jupyterlab kernel is a different virtual environment than jupyterlab is being run from. I think ipylab needs to be installed in both virtual environments for this to work.

Comment: @SimonRochester not even. Installed it in every kernel, venv, whatever you want. Restarted everything. this is returning an empty list.

Comment: But the actual docmanager:save works fine :D

Answer (score 2):

JupyterLab has a bulit-in auto-save function. You can configure the time interval using the Advanced Settings Editor, the Document Manager section (see screenshot below).

[image: autosave config]

However, if you *really* want a JavaScript solution you could just invoke the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> with:

```
from IPython.display import display, Javascript

display(Javascript(
    "document.body.dispatchEvent("
    "new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {key:'s', keyCode: 83, ctrlKey: true}"
    "))"
))
```

this will only work as long as you do not change focus to a different notebook. However, you can always use an invisible HTML node such as input to reclaim the focus first:

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML

script = """
this.nextElementSibling.focus();
this.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {key:'s', keyCode: 83, ctrlKey: true}));
"""
display(HTML((
    '<img src onerror="{}" style="display:none">'
    '<input style="width:0;height:0;border:0">'
).format(script)))
```

And you can always wrap the script in `window.setTimout` or `window.setInterval` - but it should not be needed thanks to the built in auto-save function of JupyterLab.

Comment: Note: this will need adjustment on Mac OS which uses different default keys for save.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great solution. I wonder if there is a way to make jupyter save even when my screen is black, and my browser might not be active, so a server-side method that does not require an active client?

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to share a really small tweak of the other solution by krassowski that works for JupyterLab on MacOS:

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML

script = """
this.nextElementSibling.focus();
this.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {key:'s', keyCode: 83, metaKey: true}));
"""
display(HTML((
    '<img src onerror="{}" style="display:none">'
    '<input style="width:0;height:0;border:0">'
).format(script)))
```