# Jupyter notebook save checkpoint with function

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

So with the following command it is possible to save the Jupyter Notebook:

```
Javascript('IPython.notebook.save_checkpoint();')
```

This works.
However I want to save within a function. But the following doesn't seems to work:

```
def save_file():
      Javascript('IPython.notebook.save_checkpoint();')
 

save_file()
```

Why is it not working?

Comment: Does this answer work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/69011143/16642495

Comment: Nope, does not work for me.